# Problem setting GPIO bits using PINSEL Registers

Tags: c, arm, nxp-microcontroller

Could someone please explain me how does this

```
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~(0x03 << 18);
```

clears bits 18 and 19 of Port 1? Would

```
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~(1 << 18);
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~(1 << 19);
```

give the same result?

Comment: *Would `LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~(1 << 18);
LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ~(1 << 19);` give the same result?"* **Yes in principle**, but in more steps, not atomically.

Comment: They are equivalent. In the first case you are aligning 2 clear bits, in the second you are doing them individually, although the effect on the *device* may well be **different** if they are not done at the same time (speaking generally).

Comment: It should become clear to you if you write the number 3 in binary on paper and shift it to the left by 18 places.

Answer (score 1):

Your question shoes that you need to learn logical and binary operations

From codescope.com\

> ```
> Setting a bit. Use the bitwise OR operator ( | ) to set a bit. `number |= 1 << x;` That will set a bit x .
> Clearing a bit. Use the bitwise AND operator ( & ) to clear a bit. `number &= ~(1 << x);` That will clear bit x . ...
> Toggling a bit. The XOR operator ( ^ ) can be used to toggle a bit. `number ^= 1 << x;`
> ```

Same applies if instead of 1 you will use another number. 3 is in binary `11` and it will clear two bits.

Answer (score 0):

From a boolean point of view, yes, the two options are equivalent - using [Qalculate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287382/a-good-hex-binary-calculator) for stating the obvious (it can evaluate expressions such as `~(0x03 << 18)`):

```
~(0x03 << 18) = 1111 1111 1111 0011 1111 1111 1111 1111
~(1 << 18)    = 1111 1111 1111 1011 1111 1111 1111 1111
~(1 << 19)    = 1111 1111 1111 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

The truth table for the and boolean operation being:

```
A   B   Q
0   0   0
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

All bits [0..31] in `LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1` will stay unmodified when the bitwise `and` operation will be performed against the `1` value in the bit mask at the same position.

All bits [0..31] in `LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1` will be set to zero when the bitwise `and` operation will be performed against the `0` value in the bit mask at the same position.

So yes, `LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1` will ultimately contain the same value in both cases.

But performing the operation in two steps will result in changing two or three times in a row the functional role of your pin, depending on the value of `LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1` at the time you will start modifying it.

This may affect the behavior of what is connected to your pin in the case you would already have set values in the corresponding `LPC_GPIOn –> FIODIR` for example, or other in registers configuring any of the possible alternate functions for this specific pin.

That means configuring the GPIO mode in a single operation is probably a better option, and the two options are therefore not equivalent from an hardware point of view.